# Почему не работает hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
.info {
  color: rgba(241, 245, 4, 0.959);
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 152, 0.7);
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;
}

.info:hover {
  color: rgba(241, 245, 4, 0.959);
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 152, 0.7);
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cantent__box nigiri">
  <div class="info">
    <h3 style="padding: 70px;" id="info__hov">Нигири</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как, интересно, должно произойти событие `hover` на невидимом элементе?

```css
.info {
  color: rgba(241, 245, 4, 0.959);
  background-color: rgba(158, 158, 152, 0.7);
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: none;
}

.cantent__box:hover .info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="cantent__box nigiri">
  AAA
  <div class="info">
    <h3 style="padding: 70px;" id="info__hov">Нигири</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```